# laravel form model binding with has many through relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I wont use form model binding, and it's ok with simple models and one to one or has many relationships, but when use with has many through relationship have no effect. Is it possible? how correct handle?

> Model

```
{!! Form::label('targeting_geo', trans('campaigns.targetingGeo') . ':', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3']) !!}
{!! Form::select('targetingGeo[]', $targetingGeo, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) !!}
```

> Relation

```
    public function targetingGeo ()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\DictionariesCampaignTargetingGeo',
        'App\Models\CampaignTargetingGeo',
        'campaign_id',
        'id'
    );
}
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong. What's your Model class name for targetingGeo function?

Comment: model named Campaigns